# Repairing data source for ArcGIS XY Event Table/Layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mxd, data-source

I was given an .mxd file containing a lot of layers with broken data sources. I was able to fix most of them by looking at the old data source in the Source tab of the map property.

However, there are several layers that do not contain any data source info. All that is displayed in the `Source` tab is:

```
Data Type: XY Event Source
X Field: LONGITUDE
Y Field: LATITUDE
```

I was wondering if it is possible (and how) to find out the old data source and repair the data source?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe you can recover the data source without knowing where it is in the manner you had created it.

If you create an event layer by right clicking on a standalone table in the TOC and go to *Display XY Data* then if the link is broken you get the following text in the DataSource panel under the Source tab:

```
Data Type: XY Event Source
X Field: X_Coord
Y Field: Y_Coord
```

If you had created the XY event layer using the [GeoProcessing tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006z000000) then the source tab gives you an indication of where it was:

```
Data Type:  XY Event Source 
Feature Class:  Export_Output_Features
Location:   C:\
Feature Type:   Simple
Geometry Type:  Point
```

If you know you are going to get a load of broken links in the future it maybe wise to use the geo-processing tool to build your event layer?